# Android saving preferences privately to my app but accessible from all classes

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, saving-data

I want to save a preference so that I can access it from all classes within my app. But it should not be accessible from outside my app, since it will contain user login data.

In the Android documentation it was my understanding that `MODE_PRIVATE` should do it. But if I use MODE_PRIVATE I can only access the preference from within the class where I created it.

**Class1.java:**

```
....
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editPrefs = prefs.edit();
editPrefs.putString("myPref", "myValue");
editPrefs.commit();
...
```

**Class2.java:**

```
...
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
String myString = prefs.getString("myPref", " ");
...
```

If I call `getString` within the same class where I created it, then it returns `myValue` (even after closing the app, and without putting it again).

If I call `getString` in another class within the same app, then it returns " ".

Thanks!

Comment: Because **Context** matters. Use something like this, instead: `final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);` passing the same Context for **ctx** (possibly found with `getApplicationContext()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

For documentation see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context)

Comment: Thanks! Is it private to my app this way, or is it accessible if someone knows the used context?

Comment: I can't say that, but I suggest you not to use SharedPreferences to save login data because everyone with a rooted device can see the content of SharedPreferences. Try to save your data into a binary file, see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int)

Comment: Thanks, but isn't a binaray file accessible on a rooted device too?

Comment: Yes, but nobody execpt you can say what you saved inside your binary file, while a sqlite database is easy to read